# How can i clear my input when i'm submit my event (reactJs app)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I have 3 inputs whose value I save and click on my btn, I would like to clear these inputs.......

my function that saves the value of one of my inputs:

```
onChangeIdentity = (event) => {
this.newPlayer = Object.assign({}, this.newPlayer, { strPlayer: 
event.target.value})
 }
```

my input:

```
<Input style={{width:'30%'}} onChange={ this.onChangeIdentity } 
 ref='myFormRef' value={ this.newPlayer.strPlayer } type='text' 
 placeholder='Nom & Prenom'/>
```

and the function that must clear my input:

```
addPlayer = () => {
  console.log('my new Player: ' , this.newPlayer);
  this.setState({
   teamPlayers: [...this.state.teamPlayers, this.newPlayer]
 })

this.refs.myFormRef.value = ""
 }
```

I tried several ways to declare my refs but nothing works.....
any ideas?

Comment: When you say "clear my input," do you mean the UI surface in the browser, or do you mean something else?

Comment: @robert-harvey yes it's the ui surface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You input's values are driven by the `state` of the component `value={this.newPlayer.strPlayer}`. If you want to clear the input's value you need to clear the state which maps to it, for example:

```
this.setState({newPlayer: {strPlayer: ''}});
```

After setting the state, the component updates automatically and renders the input as empty.

Here is a full example component:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    inputValue: ""
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.inputValue}
          onChange={event => this.setState({ inputValue: event.target.value })}
        />
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            /* submit this.state.inputValue */
            this.setState({ inputValue: "" }); // reset input value
          }}
        >
          submit
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: great, that was it ;)